# Booting external hard drive removed from laptop

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

My laptop recently died, so I took the HD out of it, put it in a case to allow connecting it to a USB port and plugged it into my Desktop, a windoze box. When I tried made the USB drive the first boot device, I got a message saying there was no device installed. I've checked the UEFI settings and turned off fast  boot, but to no avail. Shouldn't this drive boot as if it were in the laptop? I have a USB flash drive with Ubuntu installed on it that boots fine, so what's the problem with the HD?

Comment: Are you sure your HDD didn't die as well? Should test it for errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few reasons why this might not work, including, but not limited to:

- **Drive failure** -- As Alexiy suggests in a comment, the disk may have been the point of failure for your laptop.
- **Logical sector size changes** -- Some external enclosures "translate" eight 512-byte logical sectors into one 4096-byte logical sector. When this happens, the partition table looks like gibberish and the disk can't be used with existing partitions.
- **BIOS vs. EFI booting** -- If the old computer booted in BIOS mode and your new computer is EFI-based, you must enable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM) to boot a BIOS-mode boot loader. If it's the other way around, you won't be able to boot your EFI-based OS on a BIOS-based computer. (At least not easily; tools like DUET and Clover can do it, but they're quite exotic and difficult to configure.)
- **EFI NVRAM variables are gone** -- If both computers boot in EFI mode, you won't be able to boot an installation made on one computer after transferring the disk to another computer because part of the EFI boot process is a pointer to the boot loader stored in NVRAM, which of course remains on your old computer. You can work around this by using my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) even on a USB flash drive or CD-R if you don't want to install it permanently. rEFInd actively scans for boot loaders instead of relying on the NVRAM. Another option is to mount the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) of the target disk and copy the boot loader to the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, as described [on this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#alternative-naming)